# MYSQL Multiple column COUNT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep a track of whom is logging onto our local server as shown in the database below.

My DB Structure is:

```
user     logon          reconnect

mike     2015-07-09
mike                    2015-07-09
mike                    2015-07-09
mike     2015-07-09
john     2015-07-09
john     2015-07-09
john     2015-07-09
pete                    2015-07-09
pete                    2015-07-09
pete                    2015-07-09
matt     2015-07-09
sara     2015-07-09
```

I am trying to build a query that gets how many DISTINCT users logon or reconnect during one day, Data should look like this:

```
date          totalcount
2015-07-09    4
```

Basically its counted 4 users on 2015-07-09.

Heres my query that shows the last 14 days `logons`, but does not include `reconnects`

```
SELECT DATE(logon) AS `date`, COUNT(DISTINCT `user`) AS totalcount
FROM user_logons
GROUP BY DATE(logon)
ORDER BY DATE(logon) DESC
LIMIT 14
```

Shows:

```
date         totalcount
2015-07-09   399
2015-07-08   513
2015-07-07   524
2015-07-06   456
2015-07-05   213
2015-07-04   300
2015-07-03   484
2015-07-02   525
2015-07-01   539
2015-06-30   536
2015-06-29   481
2015-06-28   289
2015-06-27   423
2015-06-26   509
```

I'm wanting to total both columns, combining them and then grouping by date. I'm having trouble writing the query. Please help.

Comment: In each case is the *other* date `NULL`?  If so, you can use `GROUP BY COALESCE(logon, reconnect)`

Comment: yes, if the event is a logon, then the reconnect is null

Comment: Then my solution should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to "*combine*" the two dates:

```
SELECT DATE(COALESCE(logon, reconnect)) AS `date`, COUNT(DISTINCT `user`) AS totalcount
FROM user_logons
GROUP BY DATE(COALESCE(logon, reconnect))
ORDER BY DATE(COALESCE(logon, reconnect)) DESC
LIMIT 14
```

Comment: This works fantastic, and it also cuts the ex time down by a third, by not having a subselect ! Love it !

Comment: Good call using `COALESCE()` to handle the missing data.

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to create two temporary tables.  The first one contains `user` and a `date` column for all logon events.  The second one contains a `user` and a `date` column for all reconnect events.  After `UNION`ing these two tables together, you can group by the `date` and then get the count of distinct users for each date.

```
SELECT t.date AS `date`, COUNT(DISTINCT t.user) AS totalcount
FROM
(
    SELECT `user`, DATE(logon) AS `date`
    FROM user_logons
    WHERE DATE(reconnect) ISNULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `user`, DATE(reconnect) AS `date`
    FROM user_logons
    WHERE DATE(logon) ISNULL
) t
GROUP BY t.date
ORDER BY t.date DESC
```

Let me add that this approach would be more attractive if you had values other than `NULL`, in which case you could not use `COALESCE()` so gracefully.

Comment: I had to backtick USER but then it worked. I'm looking to imrove the database, as if I could pull session info, then I would not have to store the date in a field. I could have USER DATETIME SESSION EVENT

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.date AS `date`, COUNT(DISTINCT t.user) AS totalcount
FROM
(
    SELECT user, COALESCE(logon,reconnect) AS `date`
    FROM user_logons
) t
GROUP BY t.date
ORDER BY t.date DESC
```

I have tried to combine Tim Biegeleisen's solution and  PM 77-1's solution .

Just tried to help .

Comment: My solution does **not** require a sub-query.

Comment: Yes , that is the best solution :)